# Displays the photos from firebase storage only after refreshing the particular page twice

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I have been using firebase storage to store the images.
For retrieving the files from the storage, i have used listAll() function inside useEffect.

The problem is, it retrieves the file only after saving this file in vsc twice.
On initial render,the response is:

{prefixes: Array(0), items: Array(0)}
items
:
[]
prefixes
:
[]
[[Prototype]]
:
Object

After re-saving the file in vsc,the response is:

prefixes: Array(0), items: Array(3)}items: (3) [Reference, Reference, Reference]prefixes: [][[Prototype]]: Object

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { getStorage, ref, listAll,getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { useAuth,uploadPurchase} from '../config/firebase.js';

const Quotes = () => {

  const [imageList,setImageList]=useState([])

  const storage = getStorage(); 
  const currentUser=useAuth()  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

      // Create a reference under which you want to list
      const listRef = ref(storage, `/images/${currentUser.uid}/quotes/`);

  useEffect(() => {

        // onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        //   if (user) {
        //       console.log("madhav")
        //       const uid = user.uid;
        //       console.log(uid+" Logged in currently")
        //       // ...
        //   } else {
        //       console.log("No token found")
        //       navigate("/signin")
        //   }
        //   });

            listAll(listRef)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res)
              res.items.forEach((item)=>{
                getDownloadURL(item).then((url)=>{
                  return setImageList((prev=>[...prev,url]))
                })
              })
      
            })
            },[]);
      

const orderProduct=(index)=>{
  const listItems=imageList.map((item)=>item.index===index?{...item}:{item})
  console.log(listItems[index])

  uploadPurchase(listItems[index],currentUser,setLoading)
} 

 
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='card' style={{padding:50}}>
        <div className='card-title'>
          <h3>My Quotes </h3>
 
          <hr></hr>
          <div className='card-body'>
      {imageList.map((url,index)=>{
        return(
        <div className='container' key={index}>
          <div className='card' >
            <div className='card'>
              {index}:
              <div className='card-img-top'>
            <img src={url}  style={{height:20}}/>
            </div>
            <div className='input-group'>
            <button className='btn-info' type='image' onClick={()=>orderProduct(index)}>Order</button>
            </div>      
        </div>        
        </div>  
        </div> 
        )
        
      })}
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Quotes;
```

Upload Purchase function:

```
export async function uploadPurchase(file, currentUser, setLoading) {
  const fileRef = ref(storage, `/images/${currentUser.uid}/purchase/${v4()}.png`);

  setLoading(true);
  
  const snapshot = await uploadBytes(fileRef, file);
  const photoURL = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);

  updateProfile(currentUser, {photoURL});
  
  setLoading(false);
  alert("Uploaded file!");
}
```

I removed [] from useEffect, but it displays the photos repeatedly to infinite.With [] in useEffect, it does not display the photos on inital render.But, when i edit and save the particular page in vsc,
it displays the photos.

Kindly rectify this as soon as possible